# SQL DATEDIFF returns wrong result

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-arithmetic

My SQL query is as below,

```
SELECT  CAST(-1 * DATEDIFF(hour, '21-APR-2019 11:30:00 AM', '22-APR-2019 
2:15:20 PM') % 24 AS VARCHAR)
```

Output of above query:-

```
-3
```

Expected Output :-

```
-2
```

Comment: Its look like when we use `DATEDIFF(hour,...` it will only consider the value of `hour`, and ignoring values of `minute` & `second` and considering their values as `00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because:

```
DATEDIFF(hour, '21-APR-2019 11:30:00 AM', '22-APR-2019 
2:15:20 PM')
```

returns `27` and not `26`.
Change to this:

```
SELECT  CAST(-1 * (DATEDIFF(minute, '21-APR-2019 11:30:00 AM', '22-APR-2019 
2:15:20 PM') / 60) % 24 AS VARCHAR)
```

Comment: Thanks..!! Yes I did the same but if I changed the time from AM to PM then it gives me 1 hour less than actual hours

Comment: DATEDIFF() returns an integer and uses boundaries for days, hours etc. The results are not wrong. It's just how the function works.

Comment: Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017